# Get an item value from a nested dictionary inside the rows of a pandas df and get rid off the rest

Tags: python, pandas, triples, allennlp

I implemented [allennlp's OIE](https://demo.allennlp.org/open-information-extraction), which extracts subject, predicate, object information (in the form of ARG0, V, ARG1 etc) embedded in nested strings. However, I need to make sure that each output is linked to the given `ID` of the original sentence.

I produced the following pandas dataframe, where `OIE output` contains the raw output of the allennlp algorithm.

**Current output:**

| sentence | ID | OIE output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'The girl went to the cinema' | 'abcd' | {'verbs':[{'verb': 'went', 'description':'[ARG0: The girl] [V: went] [ARG1:to the cinema]'}]} |
| 'He is right and he is an engineer' | 'efgh' | {'verbs':[{'verb': 'is', 'description':'[ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:right]'}, {'verb': 'is', 'description':'[ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:an engineer]'}]} |

My code to get the above table:

```
oie_l = []

for sent in sentences:
  oie_pred = predictor_oie.predict(sentence=sent) #allennlp oie predictor
  for d in oie_pred['verbs']: #get to the nested info
    d.pop('tags') #remove unnecessary info
  oie_l.append(oie_pred)

df['OIE out'] = oie_l #add new column to df
```

**Desired output:**

| sentence | ID | OIE Triples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'The girl went to the cinema' | 'abcd' | '[ARG0: The girl] [V: went] [ARG1:to the cinema]' |
| 'He is right and he is an engineer' | 'efgh' | '[ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:right]' |
| 'He is right and he is an engineer' | 'efgh' | '[ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:an engineer]' |

Approach idea:

To get to the desired output of 'OIE Triples' , I was considering transforming the initial 'OIE output' into a string and then using regular expression to extract the ARGs. However, I am not sure if this is the best solution, as the 'ARGs' can vary. Another approach, would be to iterate to the nested values of  `description:` , replace what is currently in the OIE output in the form of a list and then implement `df.explode()` method to expand it, so that the right sentence and id columns are linked to the triple after 'exploding'.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second idea should do the trick:

```py
import ast
df["OIE Triples"] = df["OIE output"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df["OIE Triples"] = df["OIE Triples"].apply(lambda val: [a_dict["description"]
                                                         for a_dict in val["verbs"]])
df = df.explode("OIE Triples").drop(columns="OIE output")
```

In case `"OIE output"` values are not truly `dict`s but `str`ings, we convert them to `dict`s via `ast.literal_eval`. (so if they are `dict`s, you can skip the first 2 lines).

Then we get a list for each `val`ue of the series that is composed of `"description"`s of the outermost dict key'ed by `"verbs"`.

Finally `explode` this `description` lists and `drop` the `"OIE output"` column as it is no longer needed.

to get

```
                              sentence      ID                                      OIE Triples
0        'The girl went to the cinema'  'abcd'  [ARG0: The girl] [V: went] [ARG1:to the cinema]
1  'He is right and he is an engineer'  'efgh'                  [ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:right]
1  'He is right and he is an engineer'  'efgh'            [ARG0: He] [V: is] [ARG1:an engineer]
```

Comment: was not aware of the 'ast' method. Cheers!! I also found another approach to solve it, which is more time consuming but it works: transform the initial df to a dict with 'to_dict' ; pop the unwanted nested items, and transform back to a new df.